# Архитектура БД интернет-магазина

Tags: sql, база-данных, архитектура, структуры-данных

Есть интернет-магазин велотоваров. Всего имеется около 40 категорий товаров. У каждой категории свои свойства(поля). Какуй архитектуру посоветуете сделать? 40 таблиц, чтобы у каждой категории была своя таблица? Я поначалу делал так: таблица товаров(с общими для всех категорий свойствами) и таблица для хранения свойств.

Comment: вот то что было "по началу" гораздо лучше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А через неделю начальству что-то стукнет в голову: старые 40 категорий плохие, не годные, срочно переходим на новую классификацию из 100 категорий. А ещё через неделю: вернуть всё как было. И что же, создавать-удалять таблицы? Не надо этого. Поначалу было правильно.

Answer (score 1):

Товары однозначно лучше хранить в одной таблице, вместе со всеми свойствами. Если свойств много, и они все могут быть разными - то свойства лучше вынести в отдельную таблицу.

> Я поначалу делал так: таблица товаров(с общими для всех категорий свойствами) и таблица для хранения свойств.

А в чем на данный момент проблема дальше продолжать так делать?